# How to lock the rotation?

Tags: java, android

when i create an app i do not have problems with portrait mode, but when i put google maps it allow to view on landscape mode. Here's my code:

**Android Manifest:**

```
<activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:screenOrientation="sensorPortrait"
        android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|keyboard">
```

**MainActivity.java:**

```
setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_SENSOR_PORTRAIT);
```

please help me to solve this problem and sorry for bad english

Comment: If you want to lock it use `SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT`

Comment: i've tried it, but still it allow apps on landscape mode

Comment: Oh, you want to lock a different app? I don't think it's possible.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following in `AndroidManifest.xml` to lock your `MainActivity` activity, no need to write anything in `MainActivity.java` file...

```
 <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|keyboard">
```